# Running .dtsx packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have recently installed SSMS 2022 V18 on my D: drive to conserve some space on the C:
When I try to execute the `.dtsx` file it says that there is no program available to execute it.
Is there  some way to make this work or do I have to re install SSMS on the default C: drive.

10/27/22
Loaded SQL server 19 developer version. included the Integration service. Now I can import my dtsx files and execute them. So far so good. What I would like to do is run the .dtsx packages using DTexec.exe.  I follow the example of executing dtexec running a file dtexec /f "d:\documents\sql\hits.dtsx" and it complains about the version numbers.
***Package migration from version 8 to version 3 failed with error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.".***

THe dtsx file was created while running sql server 19 SSMS v 18.12.1. Should I load the SSMS package from SQL19?

Any other info would great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SSIS packages are executed by

- DTEXEC.exe  for command line runs (requires installation of SQL Server Integration Services Service to pass a licensing check)
- Custom code referencing the SQL Server assemblies
- The managed object model in the SSISDB https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/a-glimpse-of-the-ssis-catalog-managed-object-model/ba-p/387892

That's it, those are the three "runners" of SSIS packages. Using SSMS to run a package depends on "how" you were doing it versus what you're attempting now. Ultimately, you're connecting to a database and asking it to run a package.

If the package is in the SSISDB, it's using MOM.

It you were running a job, it's dtexec.exe

If you connected to the Integration Services connection node "thing" in SSMS, that's using dtexec, the 64 bit version I think?

[image]

If that's the case, changing SSMS likely also involved changing versions of SSMS which is version specific from what I can tell with that connector option.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I came up with a solution for executing dtsx packages from another program.
the program that I want to run is DTExecUI.exe. In my case that's found in
"D:\Program Files\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTExecUI.exe"

This program takes a parameter /f to indicate that is to get the data from a file and then the file location. example  " /f D:\Documents\SQL\ipdata.dtsx.

Having figured all that out I wrote a little console app in VB that take the file name as a input parameter and launches DTExecUI to execute the file.

```
Imports System

Module Program
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim app As String = "D:\Program Files\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn\DTExecUI.exe"
    Console.WriteLine(args(0))
    Dim Arguments As String = "/f " & args(0)
    LaunchProc(app, Arguments)
End Sub
Sub LaunchProc(fileNam As String, ByVal Optional arg As String = "",Optional wt As Boolean = True)
    Dim p As New Process
    p.StartInfo.FileName = fileNam
    If arg > "" Then p.StartInfo.Arguments = arg
    p.Start()
    If wt Then p.WaitForExit()
End Sub
End Module
```

To make make it so I can run the dtsx file directly by double clicking on it. I associated the dtsx file extension with my little program. Works like a charm.